# Transferring from Windows 10 to Ubuntu, 3 disks with NTFS filesystem and a new SSD with Ubuntu installed

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, ntfs, migration

On Windows 10 I had this setup. On the main disk I had the OS, on the second disk I had all my personal files mounted with first drive  (so if the OS breaks down I have my files safe), and on the third drive I had some large files, games and backups.

Since I now have switched to Ubuntu, I have Ubuntu with ext4 filesystem on my first drive, an SSD, but my other drives are still ntfs. Can I leave the other drives as ntfs or do I need to reformat them to a different file system? I can access the disks with no problem from Ubuntu. At a later date would like to transfer home to my second drive to have the same situation as before, so do I need to change the filesystem of the other three ntfs drives?

Comment: no I have a ntfs drive as a data drive on my system and have linked my music,dl,docs,pics, and videos file folders to ones on that ntfs drive (you should be able to move your hole /home to another drive)

Comment: IF not dual booting with Windows, make sure you ahve a Windows repair flash drive. NTFS needs maintenance that you cannot do from Linux. If corrupted you have to run chkdsk or defrag which only work from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You ask " Can I leave the other drives as ntfs or do I need to reformat them to a different file system? ". In short words answer is "Yes, you can leave drivers as ntfs". In long words answer is "If you planning abandon windows then you, probably, need to reformat."

Comment: Thanks for the answer